# Handling multiple tap targets inside of a ListView or RadListView (NativeScript)

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm building a "news feed" view where users can interact with posts in the usual ways:

- Tapping on the post content brings you to its detail screen
- Tapping the like button likes the post
- Tapping the comment button starts a composer

For performance reasons, I'm trying to use a `ListView` instead of a `ScrollView` so that the feed can take advantage of recycling, deferred rendering, etc. Of course, each post is one "row" in the list.

Here's the catch: per the docs, I can only listen for the `itemTap` event on the entire row. I can technically put a `tap` listener on the like button, but that prevents the `itemTap` event from firing. That wouldn't be a huge deal, but `tap` fires on the button even if someone taps the screen simply to stop scrolling. The `itemTap` event compensates for this, and only fires when the user deliberately taps the row (not just to stop scrolling). As such, I need to take action based on `itemTap`, not the button's `tap`.

I've looked into ways to tell NativeScript to propagate the `tap` event from the button up to the ListView, but everything I've found is specifically about preventing propagation.

It really feels like I'm missing something here. So many apps have feed style views these days, and there are plenty of views that have multiple "buttons" per row. What is the correct approach here? Does NativeScript just not have a way to handle this?

Comment: How about checking this sample app "Restaurant Menu App" and "News Feed with Images and Text Items"  - somewhat closely meeting your requirement - https://market.nativescript.org/?tab=samples&framework=all_frameworks&category=all_samples

Comment: If you add a tap event to a specific element in list item template, that will of course prevent itemTap but clicking anywhere else on the template will still trigger itemTap.

Comment: @Baskar the restaurant app actually is doing the same thing, however they have the same issue where you can accidentally trigger the like button's `tap` even when you are trying to just stop scrolling.

Comment: @Manoj right, but as described above, it's possible for a user to accidentally "like" something (as an example) when they are actually just tapping the screen to stop scrolling. Can you think of any way to get around this? That's why I'm trying to propagate the event up so I can still listen for the `itemTap` event which doesn't fire when the user is just tapping to stop scrolling.

Comment: Sorry, at least I didn't hit that. Touching a button while scrolling do not usually fire tap event. Do you have Playground sample?